# NW-700 Sound issue

Tags: microphone

I recently bought a NW-700 (Please keep in mind for all of this, I am very new to this) 
([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00XOXRTX6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XOXRTX6))

I am trying to set it up. I know that it requires a phantom power supply for the sound to not be very quiet, so I bought one. I currently have my microphone going into my phantom power supply and my phantom powersupply going into a mic jack to usb converter then my converter to the computer. I am using audacity to record, and the audio strength is actually weaker than my audio strength of a headset.

[image]
Does anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong? do I need a sound card in my desktop? I greatly appreciate any help what so ever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buzzing, Hissing input level issues BM-700 BM-800 NW-800 Neewer/Floureon](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the setup with my "inner eye", but this is generally how you want to approach a mic setup:

Your mic DOES require phantom. You DO know that and this is one big plus.
You have been talking about a "phantom supply" wich sound like an audio interface to me. Most interfaces require you to actually activate phantom power on the interface. So check that first.

Next in line is the connection from your interface to the recording device (I take it, that your computer serves just as that). Now your computer and your interface do always come with an integrated soundcard, but if you have an interface, then you should use this one. To achieve this, you are going to want to hit the settings in the respective software (audacity in your case) and select it as your default . 
Maybe check this link :
[Audacity Manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_selecting_your_recording_device.html)
The interface should pop up as audio host, once it's correctly connected to your computer.

Once you did all that, you will probably not get a satisfying result just yet. As for the last step you will want to look on the interfaces manufacturers page for the respective firmware and install this on your computer.

From there on you should be good to go!! :)

Cheers! ;)